Landing at Frankfurt (FRA) airport I need a train to Dusseldorf as well as the reverse back to (FRA) from Dusseldorf. Which station do I use?
I am flying in from Prague to Frankfurt (FRA).  I need to get to Dusseldorf and thought train would be quicker than a second flight.  I'm seeing there are two separate train stations, one basically in the airport and the other about 10-20 minute walk.  Which one do I use?  I keep seeing "Flughafen Fernbf which I think is the second one.  The main issue is when I take the train back from Dusseldorf to Frankfurt (hopefully airport) it needs to be pretty early since my flight leaves at 1025 AM.  Can anyone tell me which train station to use?

Because this is duplicate and will likely be closed just a comment: There's no issue with this connection at any time of the day. Fast trains are 3 per hour during the day and at least once per hour during the night.

Note that the 10 minute walk from Fernbahnhof is through an enclosed corridor with a tiled floor - you're basically walking through an "airport extension". No fresh air :) , no rain or wind, no streets to be crossed, a really smooth floor to easily push or pull along your suitcase. It's really not worth trying to get a train to the other station (Regionalbahnhof) to avoid this 10 minute walk.

Fernbahnhof has the direct, and much much faster, connections, but you can get to Düsseldorf from either stop. When searching trains on bahn.dk you just put in "Frankfurt(M) Flughafen" and it will search on both.
